# load firefox profile to selenium driver

Tags: python, windows, selenium, firefox

I created a profile using firefox -p. When I run the code:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/Edgar/Google Drive/USC workspace/Network_Scanner/lsjz2vv9.projectProfile')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

Firefox opens but there are not files created in the profile lsjz2vv9.projectProfile. The only file in there is times.json . I am mainly interested on the sessionstore-backups/recovery.js file